# How can I edit returned path from multer to remove a particualr word?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, multer

I am using multer with express, when I upload the file multer's storage engine returns a path that also includes the **public** folder which is used by express static as I am using ejs template. Is there any way so that the returned path don't include the **public** folder name in it?

**// Node App Configs**

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/profile', express.static('uploads'));
```

**// Storage Engine**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/upload',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
   limits:{
       fileSize: 10485760
   }
})
function errHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        res.json({
            success: 0,
            message: err.message
        })
    }
}
app.use(errHandler);
```

**// Path that is being returned by multer**

```
public\upload\profile_1609198415143.PNG
```

Is there any way so that this path that is returned don't include **"public\ "** in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc [File information](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information), we know `req.file.path` is the full path to the uploaded file. It generated by `path.join(destination, filename)` statement, see [disk.js#L37](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/storage/disk.js#L37).

You can remove the `public/` string like this:

```js
console.log(req.file);
const path = req.file.path.split('/').slice(1).join('/');
console.log(path);
```

Output:

```
{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname:
   'Stack Exchange personalized prediction data 2020-12-21.json',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/json',
  destination: './public/upload',
  filename: 'file_1609299871948.json',
  path: 'public/upload/file_1609299871948.json',
  size: 99765 }
upload/file_1609299871948.json
```

Comment: I tried the same but I am getting an empty log insted of the sliced path. Here's what I did:

    const submittedFile = req.file.path.split('/').slice(1).join('/');
    console.log(submittedFile);

Comment: const submittedFile = req.file.path;

    const oneSp = submittedFile.split('`\`');

    console.log(oneSp);  //[ 'public\\upload\\profile_1609333266674.gif' ]

    console.log(oneSp.splice(1));    // [ ]

My console log shows [ ] empty array after I splice